# Rewriting a do-block using bindings and lambdas in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binding, monads

My Professor has given me the following task:

```
data Expr = Num Double | Add Expr Expr

evalDo :: Expr -> Maybe Double
evalDo (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else return a 
evalDo (Add a b) = do 
                    x <- evalDo a
                    y <- evalDo b
                    return (x + y)
```

Rewrite this function using only (>>=) and lambda expressions.
This is the template I **have** to use:

```
evalBd :: Expr -> Maybe Double
evalBd (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else return a 
evalBd (Add a b) = _____ a >>= _____ _____ -> _____ _____ >>= \b' -> _____ (a' + _____ )
```

The Blanks have to be fill in. My Idea was something like ...

```
evalBd (Add a b) = evalBd a >>= \b' _____ -> _____ _____ >>= \b' -> return (a' + b' )
```

But I am unable to solve this riddle.
I am doing an exam on this topic next weak.

Comment: I believe ``\`` and `b'` each fill one of the blanks on the left of the `->`, where you are putting both in the same blank. I'm afraid this isn't a terribly well-written question on your professor's part.

Comment: Or rather, `a'` should be the parameter of the first function as well; `a'` is the result of `evalDo a` (previously called `x`), and `b'` is the result of `evalDo b` (previously called `y`).

Comment: You can't `\b' ` twice, use another variable. You used `x` and `y` in the `do` block. Note that in `____ ____` the first blank could be ` \ ` and the second one could be a variable name like your `b'`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple once you get it. I'm not going to give you the exact answer, but what you need in order to solve it. Here is what you need to know:

- `do e1 ; e2` is the same as `e1 >> e2`
- `do x <- e1; e2` is the same as `e1 >>= \x -> e2`

I highly suggest you read up on monads, probably the Haskell wikibook.